# Finding number of elements of order 2 or 4

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

[image]

I know in a cyclic group, the number of elements of order $n$ is $\phi(n)$ but I'm not sure what's being done to find it in the direct product.

For example, $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$, there are 7 elements of order 2 and what's done is $\phi(2) * 4 + 3$ but ...why that exactly? Similarly for elements of order 4.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by $\mathbb Z_n$ you mean the group of integers mod $n$ and addition.
In the following all groups will be of order $2^n$ for some $n \ge 0$.
Let $O(n,G)=$ the number of elements of order $2^n$ in $G$.
Then $O(k,\mathbb Z_{2^n}) = 2^{k-1} \text { for }1\le k \le n \text { and } 0 $ otherwise.

**Theorem**:$$O(k,G \oplus H) =O(k,G)\sum_{i=0}^{k}O(i,H)+ O(k,H\sum_{j=0}^{k}O(j,G) -O(k,G)O(k,H)$$
**Proof**: By counting as follows:
Let $|(g,h)|=2^k$ in $G\oplus H$ then $\max \{|g|, |h|\}=2^k$ so
either $|g|=2^k \text { and } |h| \le 2^k$ or vice versa. The first term in the sum counts the first possibility, the second term counts the vice versa and the third term counts the overlap, if any.

**Answer** to posted problem follows from application of Theorem, sequentially if needed. For example:
$O(0,\mathbb Z_{2^3} \oplus \mathbb Z_{2^1}) = 1(1)+1(1)-1(1)=1$
$O(1,\mathbb Z_{2^3} \oplus \mathbb Z_{2^1}) = 1(1+1)+1(1+1)-1(1)=3$ 
$O(2,\mathbb Z_{2^3} \oplus \mathbb Z_{2^1}) = 2(1+1)+0(1+1+2)-2(0)=4$
$O(3,\mathbb Z_{2^3} \oplus \mathbb Z_{2^1}) = 4(1+1)+0(1+1+2+4)-4(0)=8$
For a total of 16 elements.

The Theorem (or some generalization of it) is probably true for an arbitrary prime in place of $2$. I just proved what I needed to answer the question.

Comment: With the given groups, I guess it also wouldn't be much work to count the orders of each element one by one.